# Determining local security policy with xp_regread

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, windows-security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading Local Group Policy / Active Directory Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501234/reading-local-group-policy-active-directory-settings)

I'm trying to write an audit script for sql server 2005+.

One of the items I'd like to see in the script output is a list of the actual settings being verified by the 'Enforce Password Policy' flag.  I know that the actual settings referred to are inherited from the OS, so I was hoping that I could use xp_regread (or xp_instance_regread) to read the relevant registry keys, but I don't know which ones they are.

All my searches keep pointing me to the secpol.msc snap-in, which shows the info I want, but I was hoping to get that info added into my sql script.

Bottom line:

Which registry keys can I look for with xp_regread to get info on the local security policy?  If I can't do it that way, how else can I get the info into the results of a sql statement?